# Insert values from checkboxes in various tables?

Tags: php, database

[image]

wich contains a list of students on the left and a lot of skills to assign to each student.

Each student have it´s own table with the full skill list (HTML, CSS, ...). Now whats a simple way to get value from the checkboxes and assign them to the corresponding student table?

The purpose is to creating a graph for each student showing their skillset :-) ah, sorry for my poor english.

Comment: And what would your (x)html structure look like?

Comment: Hi Thomas, the entire table is wrapped in a form and i get the studentnames and skills from the db -> http://dl.dropbox.com/u/419629/xhtml.png

Comment: Uhm... looking at your picture, I wonder why every student has a dedicated table (`SELECT skill FROM Alexander_Merola`). Wouldn't it make more sense to have a table for all student skills and then an n:m table linking the students with the skills (columns *id*, *name*) and a value corresponding to the checkbox (columns *student_id*, *skill_id*, [boolean] *has_skill*) ? Or alternatively, you could use an INT column with a bit mask of skills (first bit = HTML, second = CSS etc.). Plus, the students' attributes should be escaped before being printed to protect against cross-site-scripting(XSS).

Comment: Yes Archimedix, that would be the right solution - but i´m not sure how this works later when i use jpgraph to create the graph for each student and read out his skills.

Comment: To read the skills with my proposed n:m table schema, you would use `SELECT sk.name FROM skills AS sk JOIN student_skills AS ss ON sk.id = ss.skill_id WHERE ss.student_id = [ID] AND ss.has_skill` (`student_skills.has_skill = 1` if using an integer type instead of boolean for `has_skill`). You'd get the same results as in your layout. Example of the query with student name match: `SELECT sk.name FROM skills AS sk JOIN student_skills AS ss ON sk.id = ss.skill_id JOIN students AS st ON ss.student_id = st.id WHERE st.name = 'Alexander Merola' AND ss.has_skill`.

Comment: I meant `ss.has_skill = 1` for integer types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print the form using a scripting language like PHP. Use a smart naming for checkboxes, then put the logic to retrieve data in the script that receive the post form.

If you use php, u can use

```
<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="paul[skill1]" value=1>
    <input type="checkbox" name="paul[skill2]" value=1>
    ...
    <input type="checkbox" name="robert[skill1]" value=1>
    <input type="checkbox" name="robert[skill2]" value=1>
    ...
</form>
```

when submitting the page, the $_POST result will be

```
$POST = array(
  [paul]   = array( [skill1]=> 1, [skill3]=>1) //paul has skills 1 and 3
  [robert] = array( [skill1]=> 1, [skill4]=>1) //paul has skills 1 and 4
)
```

if you want to do it everything on the frontend, you should use JQuery, but than managing data it's more difficult.
I suppose you have PHP skills, otherwise use a Spreadsheet to do this

Comment: Thanks Mr. Presley - i will try it later but it seems very good :-)